# Is their any way to connect QB without click update status or set autorun the QB webconnector?

Tags: java, web, quickbooks

I have an application. If I click Vendor save button from my application then the vendor details need to pass to the QB. Is that possible ? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the QuickBooks Web Connector - no.

You have to either wait for the Web Connector to auto-run, or click the "Update Selected" button in the Web Connector to force it to run.